# The error the module 'numpy' has no attribute 'arrange' keeps on that message

Tags: python, nlp-question-answering

[image]

[image]

I've tried but the error message keeps being:

> "error the module 'numpy' has no attribute 'arrange'"

What is problem?

Comment: The function you’re looking for is `arange()`, not `arrange()`.

Comment: Welcome! Please [do not post code, errors and logs as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), but copy the relevant parts into the question instead, refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you have or make a file name of 'numpy.py' in your directory. delete it. 
maybe it'll be helpful.

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer before answering